# Using Commons-VFS over HTTP

Tags: java, http, apache-commons-vfs

I am trying to browse and retrieve files from an HTTP server using the Commons VFS to implement the directory browsing functionality, find below my code snippet,

```
try {
    StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
    manager.addProvider("http", new HttpFileProvider());
    manager.setCacheStrategy(CacheStrategy.ON_CALL);
    manager.setFilesCache(new SoftRefFilesCache());
    FileObject fileObject = manager.resolveFile("http://localhost");
    System.out.println(fileObject.getChildren());
} catch (FileSystemException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when i run this code i get the following exception,

```
org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of "http://localhost/" because it is not a folder.
at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:527)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.impl.DecoratedFileObject.getChildren(DecoratedFileObject.java:105)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.cache.OnCallRefreshFileObject.getChildren(OnCallRefreshFileObject.java:105)
at VFSClient.main(VFSClient.java:31)
```

But the server is up and running and am able to browse the directories.

Can anyone tell me what could be reason for this error, am I missing something ??

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing a simple concrete repo on [FS2](http://robertjchristian.github.com/fs2/).  FS2 is a middleware api that handles all the CRUD, etc operations you need in a filesystem but can be backed by any persistence mechanism relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP seems not to support LIST_CHILDREN:

```
fileObject.getFileSystem().hasCapability(Capability.LIST_CHILDREN)
```

would return `false`

what version of VFS are you using? maybe v2.0 would help. The documentation says so:
http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what the documentation says, I don't think this is implemented yet. Take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VFS-199